# The conversion of energy during electroplating

Tags: electrochemistry, energy

I've made a test and i've faced a problem with a part of a question which says: "What is the conversion of energy occuring in electroplating? " I answered that it is conversion from electric energy to chemical energy, since in electroplating, the anode is reduced to X^n+ and n+, where n+ ions are transferred through DC power supply into the cathode and then combines with X^n+ to give again X and plates the cathode, so the electric energy(transfer of electrons through the DC power supply) is converted into chemical one(change  X^n+ to solid). I want to know if my answer is correct or not and why? Helping is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

That's a good start, but there is also ohmic loss, as much of the energy is also converted to heat in the electrolyte, electrodes or even wiring.

BTW, during WWII, silver was used to replace copper bus-bars in stationary machinery such as electrolysis apparatus, freeing the copper for use in war materiel and slightly improving the efficiency of the apparatus due to its better conductivity then commercial copper.